# touchesBegan not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, touchesbegan

I have a few `UITextFields` in `static UITableVieweCells`, and I'm trying to dismiss keyboard when the user taps elsewhere. Here is my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
    NSLog(@"touch began");
}
```

I didn't get any `NSLogs` when I taped elsewhere. What am I doing wrong?`

I then tried `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`, and `self.tableView`, and they both didn't work.

Comment: Where is this `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method?

Comment: In the tableview's .m file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your touches are probably being swallowed by the table view cells.  Try putting your keyboard dismiss code in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` on your table view delegate instead.

EDIT:

Perhaps then you ought to use some combination of that and gesture recognizers:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *navBarTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:navBarTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tableViewTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard:)];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tableViewTap];
```

Comment: If I do that, then if the user  taps on the nav bar, then `[self.view endEditing:YES]` won't get called.

Answer (score 0):

Touchesbegan is not called in UIScrollview and UITableview is a subclass of uiScrollview so make subClass of your UITableview and implement all

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

// If not dragging, send event to next responder
  if (!self.dragging){ 
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event]; 
  }
  else{
    [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
  }
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

// If not dragging, send event to next responder
    if (!self.dragging){ 
     [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event]; 
   }
   else{
     [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
   }
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

  // If not dragging, send event to next responder
   if (!self.dragging){ 
     [self.nextResponder touchesBegan: touches withEvent:event]; 
   }
   else{
     [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
   }
}
```